# Vagrant Package Include Files are missing

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I can't figure out how to get included files from a packaged vagrant box.

The package is created with:

```
$ vagrant package --include mydirectory/ --output mypackage.box
```

Then the box is added

```
$ vagrant box add mypackage.box --name myPackageWithFiles
```

Then init and vagrant up

```
$ vagrant init myPackageWithFiles
$ vagrant up
```

But when I ssh into the newly created vagrant box, there is no "mydirectory/"

I do see it on my local machine though:

```
$ ls ~/.vagrant.d/boxes/myPackageWithFiles/0/virtualbox/include/
mydirectory/
```

How do I get this directory into my vagrant box? Do I have to add something to the Vagrantfile?

Comment: most likely you corrupted your Vagrantfile, and the config.vm.box is pointing to the wrong box

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your Vagrant file, just before the `end`-line:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "~/.vagrant.d/boxes/myPackageWithFiles/0/virtualbox/include/mydirectory/", "~/mydirectory"
```

The first parameter is the local and the second is the remote path of the folder.

---

*Also there are a lot of other parameters, which you can read about [here](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html).*

Comment: If I were to go this route, I would probably use NFS instead. But this seems like a hack. I would rather find out why the files weren't included when I do vagrant init/up in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `--base` option to `vagrant package`. Otherwise it ignores your include options. If you are using VirtualBox, the argument to `--base` is the name of the virtual machine according to VirtualBox, which will be something like mybox_default_1470762777375_10784. Easiest way to find this name is to open the VirtualBox Manager GUI.

I am new to creating Vagrant boxes and found this behavior quite strange.